# LT3845 SHDN pin behaviour

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am understanding the working of a buck regulator LT3845 from linear tech. The datasheet is - [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3845fd.pdf).

My doubt pertains to the SHDN pin on the IC. The SHDN pin is connected to the Vcc via a voltage divider and requires approx 1.2-1.3V to turn the IC on. Now, the SHDN threshold varies with respect to Temperature. There are 2 graphs of the Shutdown Threshold vs Temperature (a rising and a falling of Shutdown threshold). What exactly is mean by Shutdown Threshold (rising/falling). The graphs are given in page 5. A screen shot is placed below -

[image: Screenshot]
What does this pertain to ? Shouldnt the behaviour/voltage for the SHDN pin be the same (be it rising or falling) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you want to have some hysteresis in your shutdown thresholds so it is not constantly oscillating between on and off states.

Usually switching the load off of real world power sources will have the voltage recover a bit, thus you would immediately switch on again, just to drop the voltage because it is being loaded.

To mitigate this problem you want the switch on to be quite a bit higher than the switch off so that you have a decent chance of preventing this oscillation and your circuit being off even when the load is gone.